# Template with Two Types Confusion C++

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm trying to make a simple template of creating an array class. However, I want to use two arguments: one typename and one int variable. I'm running into two errors and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my source which is simple and works.

```
int main()
{
    Array<int, 7> tArray;
    std::cout << tArray.getSize() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < tArray.getSize(); i++)
    {
        tArray.insert(i + 5);
        i++;
    }
    tArray.printArray();
    return 0;
}
```

The error/issue I'm having is regarding two functions in my header file.

```
#pragma once

template <typename T, int S>
class Array
{
private:
    T arr[S];
public:
    Array();
    int getSize() const;
    int insert(T val);
    void printArray();
    ~Array();
};  
cArray<T, S>::cArray() { }
template <typename T, int S>
int Array<T, S>::insert(T val)
{
    Array<T, S>* temp = new Array[S];
    temp = this;
    return temp[val];
}

template <typename T, int S>
void Array<T, S>::printArray()
{
    Array<T, S>* temp = new Array[S];
    temp = this;
    for (int i = 0; i < S; i++)
    {
        std::cout << tempArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The functions insert and printArray are not working. For the insert function, the error being returned states: Suppression State Error  C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'Array<int,7>' to 'int'
The printArray is displaying nothing.

This is the first time I'm using a template with two arguments so I'm a bit confused on what I'm doing wrong here. Any takes?

Comment: Could trim your code down to focus on the `insert` function? What do you think this function does? (Currently, it does nothing useful.)

Comment: Think about what this does `new Array[S];`.

Comment: Just trimmed the code to the functions with errors. And I want the function to add the value (val) to the array that's calling it.

Comment: @SmithJohn You have described what you want this function as a whole to accomplish. I was wondering what you think each line of it does.

Comment: @JaMiT The first line creates a temporary array. The next line would set it equal to the array/data being sent to the function (which this holds). Once the temp array has the information, I would return to the value of the number which wants to be entered while attaching it to the given slot in the array. That was the thought process behind it.

Comment: @SmithJohn Information should be edited into the question, not lost here in the comments. However: it looks like your main misunderstanding (of the several in that one function) is treating pointers as the thing to which they point. Your description of the second line would correspond to `*temp = *this`, not `temp = this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending code is here:

```
template <typename T, int S>
int Array<T, S>::insert(T val) {
    Array<T, S>* temp = new Array[S];
    temp = this;
    return temp[val];
}
```

First, you create an array of `Array`s, because you wrote an expression that looks like:

```
Type *var = new Type[count];
```

Then you change the pointer to that array to `this`. Then you try to return the element at index `val` of the array `temp`, and this element has type `Array<T, S>`. But, the return type is `int`, so, that is why the compiler complains that it cannot convert `Array<int, 7>` to `int`.

You should not use `new` here at all. You already have allocated memory for the array (it's the member variable `arr`), you just need to copy `val` into the right place in that array. To do that, you need to keep track of how many elements you already inserted in the array. (Note that `S` is a constant that just says what the maximum amount of elements is you can store.) So:

```
template <typename T, int S>
class Array {
    T arr[S];
    size_t size = 0;
...
};

template <typename T, int S>
void Array<T, S>::insert(T val)
{
    arr[size++] = val;
}

template <typename T, int S>
size_t Array<T, S>::getSize()
{
    return size;
}
```

And `printArray()` has similar issues. You should print the contents of `arr`, you should not create a new temporary array and try to print its elements.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me understand what was I was doing wrong. I thought I had to create a temporary array in order to insert each value sent over each time. I have one more quick question that is unrelated to the original question. My default constructor cArray() is underlined in a green squiggly line saying that it is uninitialized and that it should always be initialized. In my case/program, there is no need for it to be initialized though, right?

Comment: I'm not sure, since I don't see the rest of `class CArray`.